# Dynamically add validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have a formArray and on click i am calling addReps method to push a new formGroup.I want to add some validators dynamically with setValidators method but when i'm doing this i'm getting error: 
**Cannot read property 'setValidators' of undefined**. My form working fine but i can't understand why i'm getting this error.Am i doing something wrong with my formControl access this.reps.controls["mobileNumber"]?

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private stateService: StateService, private apiService: ApiService) {
   this.form = this.fb.group({
     reprepresentative: this.fb.array([]),
   });
}

addReps() {
  this.reps = this.form.controls.reprepresentative as FormArray;
  this.reps.push(this.fb.group({
    firstname: ['', [Validators.required,
     Validators.minLength(2),
     this.ValidateNames
    ]],
    surname: ['', [Validators.required,
     Validators.minLength(2),
     this.ValidateNames
   ]],
   mobileNumber: ['', [Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/)
    ]],
  isInitiator: false,
  editRep: true
  }));
  this.reps.controls["mobileNumber"].setValidators([this.SameMobileValidator,Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/)]);
  this.reps.controls["mobileNumber"].updateValueAndValidity();
}

SameMobileValidator(formControl: AbstractControl){
   let repList = this.stateService.reprepresentativeList;
   const found = repList.some(el => el.MobilePhone == formControl.value)
   if(!found) return null;
   else { return { mismatch: true }; }
}
```

I also try this:

```
  this.reps.get("mobileNumber").setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/),this.ValidateNames]);
this.reps.get("mobileNumber").updateValueAndValidity();
```

But i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.reps** is a formArray, so you should change

```
this.reps.controls["mobileNumber"].setValidators([this.SameMobileValidator,Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/)]);
```

by

```
const reprepresentativeControl = this.form.get('reprepresentative');
reprepresentativeControl.controls.forEach(c => c.get("mobileNumber").setValidators([this.SameMobileValidator,Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/)]));
reprepresentativeControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `.controls` to get specified control. Use `get()`. You are getting an exception becouse your `this.reps` is `FormArray` which when you access to `controls` property, you are getting object like this:

```
{
    1: [formControl],
    2: [formControl],
    3: [formControl]
}
```

As you can see, there is no field `mobileNumber` in `this.reps`. You have to directly access to `formControl` to get `mobileNumber` `formControl`. Or you can directly add `validator` to the field while you are building your form like have done earlier. If your validation logic validate f.e. number uniqueness, you have to attach validator on your `FormArray` (or `FormGroup`, depending on what you use) not directly on `FormControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Since ForArray are index based you have use index value to get specific formGroup controls.

**Try this:**

```
this.reps.at(0).get('mobileNumber').setValidators([=[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(69[0-9])[0-9]{7}$/),this.ValidateNames])
```

Comment: So every time i add a newRep i have to pass the index on this method to add the validator to the right control?